# Affix Bottom takes an issue after page loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my `affix` script. Everything is working right but when affix gets `affix-bottom` class and I refresh the page `affix-bottom` gets an issue it doesn't get the right position after refreshing.
Could you offer me any solution?

```
var
navbarHeight        = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true),
informationHeader   = $('.informationHeader').outerHeight(true),
informationList     = $('.informationList .item').outerHeight(true),
footerHeight        = $('footer').outerHeight(true);

$('#nav-affix').affix({
    offset: {
        top: function () {
            return (this.top = navbarHeight + informationHeader + informationList - 30);
        },
        bottom: function () {
            return (this.bottom = footerHeight + 2);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the link: http://bagrattam.com/website/terms.html

Comment: So, it's miscalculating by 34 pixels.

Comment: Yes, there is a miscalculating.

Comment: @SergChernata So you don't have any solution?